# Why are all my view controllers square shaped?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to get it to be an iphone project, but when I drag any view controller into the storyboard, it's just a weird almost-square, neither ipad nor iphone. What am I doing wrong here? Newest version of XCode.

[image]

Comment: LMFAO, WHY THE FROG AM I GETTING DOWNVOTED? LIKE THIS ISN'T A LEGITIMATE QUESTION? LIKE IT SHOULD BE OBVIOUS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a new feature called "size classes". You can use it to create a universal storyboard for iPhone and iPad at once.

But I don`t really like it so here is how to turn off: In storyboard, open utility inspector (right), then go to file inspector (left) and now disable "Use Size Classes". Then you will get the standard storyboard.

[image]

Comment: HOW THE &$@# WOULD ANYONE KNOW THAT WITHOUT ASKING SOMEONE WHO ALREADY KNEW???????

Comment: I love programming but when you're learning a new framework/language/IDE/whatever it's EXACTLY this sort of little thing that's just **SO** frustrating.

Comment: No need to remind me, remember there's an 8 minute limit before I can accept. :))))))))))))))))) If you give good answers you'll get plenty of rep over time without encouraging anyone to accept your responses.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not know that :) I thought you had forgot it :)))

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong. The default is to design with UI constraints so that the actual output size doesn't matter.

What you can do is set the size you want to preview your controller at in the options in the right hand pane. E.g.

[image]